# Using copy_to_user to append to a log?

Tags: module, linux-kernel

I have a kernel module that I'm trying to get to print out activity information to a log on a regular basis:

```
copy_to_user(output, message, strlen(message));
```

However, all it seems to be doing is overwriting the previous log entry.  What can I do to make this append information rather than overwrite?  I've considered making some kind of global variable space_taken (initialized to 0) such that

```
copy_to_user(output+space_taken, message, strlen(message));
space_taken = space_taken + strlen(message)*sizeof(char);
```

but this doesn't seem to work properly.

Comment: `but this doesn't seem to work properly.` - What exactly happens? While `output` buffer length is sufficient, your code should behave correctly.

Comment: It's overwriting, not appending.

Comment: Check that `space_taken` variable is non-zero when you *append* message. And post your other code, related to the question.